# Replacing part of the string with regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this:

```
$string ='//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6b/AkutanZero1.jpg/220px-AkutanZero1.jpg';
```

But I'm trying to replace a section of it with another:

```
$string ='//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6b/AkutanZero1.jpg/123px-AkutanZero1.jpg';
```

I'm using trying to use preg_replace, and I know that the string will always end with /thumb/(a hex value)/(two hex values)/(stuff)/(one or more numbers)-px-(stuff)

Unfortunately I haven't been successful in getting the text replaced and don't know what I'm doing wrong.

It would be easy if I could assume /(one or more numbers)-px existing only once but it could also exist in the /(stuff) part too.

```
preg_replace('/\/thumb\/[0-9a-f]\/[0-9a-f]{2}\/.+\/([0-9]+)-px-.+$/i', '328', $string);
preg_replace('/(\/thumb\/[0-9a-f]\/[0-9a-f]{2}\/.+\/)([0-9]+)(-px-.+)$/i', $1.'328'.$3, $string);
```

Comment: Preliminary look and you have a `-` before `px` in the regex that prevents it from matching. Try `preg_replace('~(/thumb/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f]{2}/.+/)([0-9]+)(px-.+)$~',  $1.'328'.$3, $string);`

Comment: That was exactly it, thank you so much!

Comment: If you really want to _guard_ against `/dddpx-` not being found in stuff, use this instead `preg_replace('~(/thumb/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f]{2}/.+/)([0-9]+)(px-(?:(?!/[0-9]+px-).)+)$~',  $1.'328'.$3, $string);` But this is unlikely since `/.+/` takes you to the _last_ `/`. In that case, you'd just need this `preg_replace('~(/thumb/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f]{2}/.+/)([0-9]+)(px-‌[^/]+)$~', $1.'328'.$3, $string);`

Comment: Can you provide two or three differing examples so we can understand the variability of your text?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your single sample input, you don't need any capture groups to get the expected result.  Just find the occurrence(s) of digits followed by `px-` and swap in your preferred value.  If this isn't robust enough, please improve your question.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/040f50e8ead0d59803155e42dc716ce0b8bffecd))

```
$string='//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6b/AkutanZero1.jpg/220px-AkutanZero1.jpg';
echo preg_replace('/\d+px-/','123px-',$string);
```

Output:

```
//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6b/AkutanZero1.jpg/123px-AkutanZero1.jpg
```